# How to get camel-mqtt endpoint to locate (resolving) my ActiveMQ on openshift/fuse

Tags: apache-camel, openshift, jbossfuse, fabric8

I'm kind of new to this so I might have missed the obvious.

I have an openshift gear with jboss fuse. I have started an ActiveMQ broker with an mqtt connector and created a camel route (using OSGi blueprint) consuming from the ActiveMQ mqtt connector on the same openshift gear. Everything works perfectly when I use the ip-address:port to the mqtt connector but that is not what I want to do. I would like to have some other solution (resolver) that doesn't make me have to point out a specific ip-address in the mqtt endpoint so I can move around the camel-route without reconfiguring it.

ActiveMQ connector config:

```
   <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" publishedAddressPolicy="#addressPolicy" uri="tcp://${OPENSHIFT_FUSE_IP}:${OPENSHIFT_FUSE_AMQ_PORT}"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt"     publishedAddressPolicy="#addressPolicy" uri="mqtt://${OPENSHIFT_FUSE_IP}:1883"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Camel-Route when it works:

```
<camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route id="mqttToLog">
    <from uri="mqtt:iot?host=tcp://127.4.22.139:1883&amp;subscribeTopicName=mytesttopic&amp;userName=admin&amp;password=xxxxxxx" id="iot_endpoint">
      <description>The MQTT endpoint for consuming data sent from the devices.</description>
    </from>
    <log message="The message contains ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" id="iot_log">
      <description>Logs all the incoming MQTT messages. This is just for verification purpouses.</description>
    </log>
    <to uri="mock:result" id="iot_mock">
      <description>Final sink for the MQTT message flow. Kept for verification.</description>
    </to>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

My camel-routes profile has feature-camel as parent and features camel and camel-mqtt.

So how do I get rid of actually having to specify the host in the endpoint, using for instance the mq group, or some other registry (fabric) or similar?

Thanks,

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a fabric then the ActiveMQ clustering feature works like this: The broker is part of a so called "broker group". The default broker is part of the group "default" which means there is a profile called `mq-client-default`. This profile will register a pre-configured ActiveMQ ConnectionFactory in the OSGi services registry. Its configured to connect to where-ever your broker is located, and will failover automatically to other brokers in the same group.

To make use of the above in Fuse 6.1 do the following:

- Create a new child container
- Add the mq-client-default profile to it
- Add the feature "mq-fabric-camel" to the mq-client-default profile. This will install a camel component called "amq" that automatically uses the connectionFactory from the mq-client-default profile.
- Deploy a camel route like the following and witness the awesomeness of JBoss Fuse :)

`<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="myRoute">
      <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=5000"/>
      <setBody>
        <simple>Hello from Camel route to ActiveMQ</simple>
      </setBody>
      <to uri="amq:queue:timermessages"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>`

The messages generated by this route will end up on the broker, no matter where the broker is, or where the camel route is.

Good luck!

P.S. The amq component uses openwire to communicate to the broker, but any other client can use whatever protocol you've enabled to consume or produce messages to your queues.